# My date field is displaying the time too. How to remove the time?

Tags: c#, date

My Date datatype is date. And it shows the time too in the form which is 12:00:00AM. But in my database It only have 6/6/2014 and 12/12/2016 and don't have this 12:00:00AM. How to remove that? Below are my appointment form codes. Please tell me how to delete the time?

[image]

2 dates now

[image]

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

public partial class member_viewappointment : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
        {
            // call BindGridView
            bindGridView();

        }
    }

    private void bindGridView()
    {
        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"].ToString());
        //get connection string from web.config
        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

        string strCommandText = "SELECT pat.pFirstName AS FirstName, aStatus AS Status,  aDate AS Date, aTime AS Time, aContact AS Contact, aHeight AS Height, aWeight AS Weight, med.mcCentre AS MedicalCentre from appointment AS app ";
        strCommandText += " LEFT OUTER JOIN MEDICALCENTRE as med on app.mcid = med.mcid";
        strCommandText += " LEFT OUTER JOIN PATIENT as pat on app.patientid = pat.patientid ";
        strCommandText += " WHERE app.patientid = " + ID.ToString();

        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);

            myConnect.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(reader);
            grdViewAppointment.DataSource = dt;
            grdViewAppointment.DataBind();
            lblResult.Text = "";

            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            lblResult.Text = "Error:" + ex.Message.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnect.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Run this query

```
private void bindGridView()
    {
        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"].ToString());
        //get connection string from web.config
        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

 string strCommandText = "SELECT pat.pFirstName AS FirstName, aStatus AS Status,  COnvert(VARCHAR(15),aDate,103) AS Date, aTime AS Time, aContact AS Contact, aHeight AS Height, aWeight AS Weight, med.mcCentre AS MedicalCentre from appointment AS app ";
    strCommandText += " LEFT OUTER JOIN MEDICALCENTRE as med on app.mcid = med.mcid";
    strCommandText += " LEFT OUTER JOIN PATIENT as pat on app.patientid = pat.patientid ";
    strCommandText += " WHERE app.patientid = " + ID.ToString();

        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);

            myConnect.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(reader);
            grdViewAppointment.DataSource = dt;
            grdViewAppointment.DataBind();
            lblResult.Text = "";

            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            lblResult.Text = "Error:" + ex.Message.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnect.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but see my above image. I added a bound field and follow your code. So now i have two dates now. How to remove the field which have the date and time. @Vignesh Kumar

Comment: Give Visible = "False" in bound field to remove from display @Jordjmax

Comment: image posteddd Thanks @Vignesh Kumar

Comment: @j Make a false of visible prprty

Comment: Lol but that date without time will be unvisible, if i do that. And the one with date and time stills display @Vignesh Kumar

Comment: @Jordjmax I can't get you. actually what's your problem

Comment: Well u told me to add the date bound field, so i added that, see the 3rd image. Then u tell me to make it visible = false. So what's the purpose of adding it, if u r telling me to make it unvisible.  @Vignesh Kumar

Comment: @Jordjmax oh u misunderstood.. you want to display onle date not time right?

Comment: erm ya. I only want to display all fields including the date with no time. I only want to get rid of the one field which have date and time. @Vignesh Kumar

Comment: @Jordjmax what databse you using and post your query

Comment: My query? i thought my codes are posted above? @Vignesh Kumar

Comment: lol actually i used jake rote code first and it work. And yours is almost same as him. But I want to give u the tick as i think u spend a lot of effect to help i guess. Did I make the right choice? i;m new here tho.  @Vignesh Kumar

Comment: You are welcome..but i think this is the proper way.. @Jordjmax

Comment: They are both the same answer but its up to you which one you vote.

Answer (score 2):

When using a DateTime you can do `.ToString("d/M/yyyy")`

you can do this in the sql `convert(varchar, aDate, 103) AS Date`

Comment: put it in the query? @Jake Rote

Comment: DATE_FORMAT(aDate,'%e/%c/%Y') AS Date

Comment: Error:'DATE_FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name. @Jake Rote

Comment: which version of sql are you using ?

Comment: my fault that was for mysql this is for mssql convert(varchar, aDate, 103) AS Date

Answer (score 1):

You can try `DataFormatString` to set the format of datetime in the bound column

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="MyDataField" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"  />
```